# How to write a library for UWP using C++/winRT (Visual Studio 2019)?

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, shared-libraries, c++-winrt

This should not be so difficult!

In normal C++ one can write static or dynamic libraries that can be used in multiple application projects. I want to do the same thing for UWP apps using C++/winRT.

I have written a simple C++/winRT UWP app that discovers Bluetooth Low Energy Devices. I used the Core UWP project template that set up all that pch.h stuff. What I want to do is to make a library out of the code I wrote that did the Bluetooth work so it can be shared across many UWP apps but I have no idea which project template I should use to do that.

I have come to the conclusion that writing a Windows Runtime Component is not what I want. I am not *making* a run time component though I need to use runtime components for the Bluetooth.

In the end I will be calling that library from a Java application but that's off in the future.

All my problems would be solved if they had a Java/winRT option (a Java language projection in Microsoft-speak).

Note that the project selection interface in Visual Studio 2019 must be very different than 2017 as none of the demos I have seen online look like what I see.

Comment: *"I have come to the conclusion that writing a Windows Runtime Component is not what I want."* - Probably the wrong conclusion, and it's entirely unclear, what led you to believe that. *"In the end I will call be calling that library from a Java application"* - I'm somewhat sure that the [xlang project](https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang) will allow you to do just that, as long as you provide a Windows Runtime Component, alongside the metadata.

Comment: @IInspectable I am not making a windows runtime component, I am making ordinary C++ classes that call windows runtime components (mainly Bluetooth Low Energy APIs). I see that there are two project templates for UWP static and dynamic libs for C++/CX, but none for C++/winRT.(Visual Studio 2019 16.0.1) In some sense I would just like to pull some of the classes I made in the C++/winRT core app and make those into a library.

Comment: If that is what you *really* want, start with the *"Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT)"* project template, change the subsystem from `CONSOLE` to `WINDOWS` and the "Configuration Type" from "Application (.exe)" to "Dynamic Library (.dll)" (modifying the entry point appropriately). Make sure to read [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries). Those issues are solved already when using COM or the Windows Runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried another approach this morning and it worked at least for a static lib. Since the code I write will use the windows runtime (but no UI related material) I started with the C++/winRT core application template, removed the UI and startup code, changed the project to a static lib instead of exe, and it worked. All that was left in the project were the classes I wrote and the pch.h and pch.cpp files with the UI WR headers removed. The project template did all the other dirty work of setting up what it needs to in order to access the runtime APIs. Will this bite me later?

Comment: @IInspectable I should also add I requested that C++/winRT templates for UWP static and dynamic libs be added analogous to the C++/CX templates that already exist.

Comment: The Core Application template generates an .appxmanifest along the way. I'm not sure whether that will pose any issues (e.g. making types available that do not have the `DualApiPartitionAttribute`, or defining preprocessor macros with adverse effects). Using the *"Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT)"* template, by contrast, is a lot closer to a standard .dll project for use by classic Desktop applications. And it sets up everything required to consume Windows Runtime types just as well.

Comment: @IInspectable I used the core app to get the correct options and have successfully modified it to get a working dll that uses BLE runtimes. The console application did not have some of the fields I needed as I recall; the minimum and target OS versions being one, without which caused me issues. IN any case, there is probably garbage in the project I don't want (like the assets) but at this time I have not tried to clean them up.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, the appmanifest is still there; it does not seem to be causing damage but I would prefer NOT to have any baggage I do not need. I do want the dll to work for UWP apps (on all Windows platforms).

Comment: Just as an aside, you may want to follow along or contribute to Scott Jones' work on a Java WinRT projection here: 

https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang/tree/scottj1s/javax/src/tool/java/javart

It's still in a very early state (the first draft hasn't hit the main branch yet) and help would be welcomed.

Comment: @BenKuhn I would certainly like to help but I do not think I have the know-how to contribute to the development. However, I certainly have the infrastructure in place to test a Java implementation looking to access the Windows Runtime Bluetooth APIs. How would I do this?

Comment: @BenKuhn how can I contact Scott Jones?

Comment: You can either reach out to him on twitter at ScottJ1s, or if you want to discuss java support, consider starting an issue in the github.com/microsoft/xlang repo, which is a better way to engage the team as a whole.